# Devexpress LookUpControl Set EditValue

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

I've got a [DevExpress LookUpEdit Control](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsLookUpEdittopic) which is populated from an SQL Server using the following code:

```
             m._Con.Open()
                Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT rRep_Group_ID AS 'ID', rRep_Group_Name AS 'Rep Group Name' FROM Rep_Group"
                Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, m._Con)
                Dim ds As New DataSet
                da.Fill(ds, "Rep_Group")

                With RepGroupcComboBox.Properties
                    .DataSource = ds.Tables("Rep_Group")
                    .DisplayMember = "Rep Group Name"
                    .ValueMember = "ID"
                End With
             m._Con.Close()
```

I'm trying to change the `editvalue` (which normally is the .Text property) so that the persons Rep' Group is automatically selected based off the value in the server. Now, I have the persons Rep' Group Name stored in a string variable `m._RepGroupName` - which is `Group 2`, I just need this to be displayed as the edit value.

But I cant seem to get it working. I've tried this, Note that RepGroupcComboBox **is** a Dexexpress lookupedit control despite me naming it a combo box:

```
     RepGroupcComboBox.EditValue = RepGroupcComboBox.Properties.GetKeyValueByDisplayText(m._RepGroup)
```

But It still returns the default `[Editvalue is null]'.

I've included a screenshot of the control during run-time below.

[image]

Comment: EditValue is not Text. It's a value from the ValueMember property (https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemLookUpEditBase_ValueMembertopic) where as Text is a value from the DisplayMember property (https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemLookUpEditBase_DisplayMembertopic). What fields did you set to these properties?

Answer (score 0):

You set your value member to ID, Edit value is response by value member. if you want to get the 'rep group name' you must set it to value member.